# How to use `case_sensitive` option in pathlib glob?

Tags: python, pathlib

In the documentation of pathlib, it says

> Path.glob(pattern, *, case_sensitive=None)

There is two things I do not understand.

1. what is the second parameter * ?
2. I want to use `case_sensitive` option. But when I run

   `somepath.glob('*.txt',case_sensitive=False)`

I got `TypeError: glob() got an unexpected keyword argument 'case_sensitive'`

How to use `case_sensitive` option in pathlib glob?

Comment: The `case_sensitive` option was added in Python 3.12, so you would need to upgrade your Python version if it isn't supported by your current version.

Comment: @blhsing Thank you so much. Indeed I am using old python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lone `*` without a parameter name indicates that everything following is a keyword-only argument. That is, with the declaration

```
def glob(pattern, *, case_sensitive=None)
```

We can pass `pattern` positionally *or* by-name, but we can only pass `case_sensitive` by name. So all of the following are valid

```
path.glob('*')
path.glob(pattern='*')
path.glob('*', case_sensitive=True)
path.glob(pattern='*', case_sensitive=True)
path.glob(case_sensitive=True, pattern='*')
```

But this is *not*

```
path.glob('*', True)
```

The Python designers wrote the function in this way to force you to write more readable code. If you were able to write `path.glob('*', True)`, then everyone reading your code (including you in two weeks) would have to go look up what that second parameter is. But with the `case_sensitive=True` syntax, it's immediately self-evident.

As for your second question, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) specifies

> *Changed in version 3.12:* The *case_sensitive* parameter was added.

So I suspect you're running a version of Python older than 3.12.